# How can I use regexes to find definitions in Python?

Tags: python, definition

This is what my prof has given us for clues:

```
text = '''I make my own cheese. Cheese is a dairy product, derived from milk and produced in wide ranges of flavors, textures and forms by coagulation of the milk protein casein. I personally really love cheese. Casein: a family of related phosphoproteins. These proteins are commonly found in mammalian milk'''

for r in re.finditer('\w+',text):  #Here, I would split my text into sentences
    word = r.group(0)
    if re.search(r'lly\b',word): #Here, I would identify a type of sentence
        print(word)
    if re.search(r'tion\b',word):   #Here, I would identify another type of sentence
        print(word)
```

Basically, what I gathered from my own text are two types of definitions; one that is integrated into the sentence usually followed by a descriptive verb ("Cheese is...") and one that is the defined word followed by a colon and its definitory (invented word?) sentence ("Casein: [...]"). I've scraped my brain the whole week trying to find a way to extract and print these sentences without any luck. As a Linguistics major who's just trying to get by, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem? any error?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to extract these two sentences using regex: "Cheese is a dairy product [...]" and "Casein: a family of [...]" from the text.